# Sending an Email Invoice and have client pay directly via invoice email

Tags: civicontribute, payment, invoice

I am wondering whether it is possible for CIVICRM to send an email 'pending invoice' to contributors and have them pay directly through the invoice. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a schedule reminder under 'Parameter >> Communication', you can choose 'Contribution' as a trigger.

For the payment this will depend on your choice, but in both cases you can send a message with a custom link (with cid & checksum) to your front-end form or your contribution page that would we have connected to a payment gateway such as Stripe or Paypal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have [invoicing enabled](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/ca/latest/contributions/invoicing/), you can find your pending contributions (**Contributions menu » Find Contributions**), select them all, then choose **Invoices - print or email** from the **Actions** menu.

You may want to check out my [altinvoice](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/altinvoice) extension - I don't actively develop it but it will allow linking directly to the user's dashboard to facilitate payment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found this little module to be quite helpful: https://civicrm.org/extensions/invoice-helper

It will generate a payment link that you can add to each email that you're sending out. Yes, it's manual, but it saves you some time.